# Matplotlib scatter/contour hybrid plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, contourf

I am trying to create a countourplot with very sparse data, without interpolation. I would like to create something like this

[image]

In other words, I would like to create a 'scatterplot/ countourplot hybrid'. Is this possible in matplotlib? If so how? Should I be using countourf() or scatterplot()? Or something else entirely?

I created an example data set below.

Many thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

In [1]:

d = {'col1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'col2': [0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0], 'col3': [0, 0.9, 0, 0, 0], 
     'col4': [0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0], 'col5': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.replace(0, np.nan)


Out [1]: 

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   0.1   0.9   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   0.3   NaN
4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

plotting with contourf():

```
y = df.index.values
x = df.columns.values
z = df
fig1 = plt.contourf(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Could you embed the image in the question?

Comment: unfortunately I do not have enough points to embed (min 10 required)!

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't realise.

Comment: You could use matplotlibs [tricontourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html) function and then mask out all the areas of the plot that should not be shown. See for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44114563/2454357) for an example.