# contour plot matplotlib on a specific background color

Tags: python, matplotlib, mapbox-gl-js

I am generating contour plots (with transparent background) for pH of water on a river, and am overlaying the generated plot on the interactive map using map box. It looks like this:
[image]

I want to overlay plot in only on the water area, and not show over the ground area.

In my understanding there should be two ways possible: 
1. While generating the image, making that part invisible
2. While overlaying the image, making that part invisible

I have tried finding solution for both but couldn't get a solution. Is there any way to go about it?

Comment: The question provides very little detail on the actual problem. Possibly it's the same as [matplotlib contourf of concave non-gridded data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426095/matplotlib-contour-contourf-of-concave-non-gridded-data).

Comment: The figures are I am using are not necessarily closed. 
I am overlaying these plot images on the interactive web map background. 
I want to edit them (according to the background color) after generating them, so that I can show them only on the water area and not on ground area.

Comment: By "actual problem" I am refering to a [mcve] of the code you have a problem with.