# How to draw a polygon (parts was bent inward) edge on a group of points with Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

I am trying to draw a polygon (concave) edge on a K-Means cluster shown below (fig_1).

[image]

With @ypnos's help, This piece of code plot everything except the edge.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MachineIntellect/dataset.ml/master/watermelon/watermelon_4_0.csv')
X = df.iloc[:,1:].to_numpy()
m0 = X[5]
m1 = X[11]
m2 = X[23]
centroids = np.array([m0, m1, m2])
labels = pairwise_distances_argmin(X, centroids)
m0 = X[labels == 0].mean(0)
m1 = X[labels == 1].mean(0)
m2 = X[labels == 2].mean(0)
new_centroids = np.array([m0, m1, m2])
plt.xlim(0.1,0.9)
plt.ylim(0, 0.8)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1])
plt.scatter(new_centroids[:,0], new_centroids[:,1], c='r', marker = '+')
for i in range(3):    
    points = X[labels == i]
    hull = ConvexHull(points)
    for simplex in hull.simplices:
        plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'r-')
```

[image]
(fig_2)

[The scikit-learn doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-kmeans-digits-py) seems to be inspiring

The question is that the edges pointed by the arrow in fig_1 are different from the correspondence in fig_2.

the edge of the polygon that was being pointed to by the arrow was bent inward (thanks to @dwilli).

Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's reminder, `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` may not be able to produce concave.

Is there any other module/package to do this (concave)?

any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: to check fig1 and fig2 you need to provide us the code/input for fig1

Comment: Convex hulls are *convex*, they won't produce concave lines.

Comment: The figure you are trying to reproduce is likely user-drawn polygons...

Comment: Some relevant links: [Method for determining if a line segment is an external edge of a Delauney triangulation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/270328/method-for-determining-if-a-line-segment-is-an-external-edge-of-a-delauney-trian), [How to deal with the (undesired) triangles that form between the edges of my geometry when using Triangulation in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457964/how-to-deal-with-the-undesired-triangles-that-form-between-the-edges-of-my-geo)

Comment: [building-concave-hulls-alpha-shapes-with-pyqt-shapely-and-arcpy](https://tereshenkov.wordpress.com/2017/11/28/building-concave-hulls-alpha-shapes-with-pyqt-shapely-and-arcpy/)

Answer (score 1):

What your inspiration shows is a Voronoi diagram. The coloring shows for any coordinate in the graph, which cluster it would be associated to.

The polygons you show in your first figure are a rough approximation of the convex hull of your cluster members. You could use `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` or `cv2.convexHull()` (from OpenCV) to compute it. The documentation of the former also gives an [example on how to plot it](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer. we are almost there. I've just updated the question. would you please take a loot at that?

Answer (score 0):

To generate the polygon you can try the below steps

- Generate polygons around each cluster treating each cluster as in individual part of the plot.
- You can create a rough polygon using the convex hull method mentioned by @ypnos, but to get a better result, have a look at the [`Delaunay triangulation method`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).
- You will generate triangular regions between the points based on a set threshold value. The threshold will ensure the best possible fit.
- Using this data, you can plot a concave hull using the extreme points. As you don't want the extreme points to be included as the vertices of the polygon, you should add a buffer to go around the points by a set value.

Expected result on some sample data

[image: Result]

There's quite a bit of code required to achieve the result, **[here](http://blog.thehumangeo.com/2014/05/12/drawing-boundaries-in-python/)** is a link to a comprehensive guide to generate the sample plot.

Comment: thanks for your answer. that is inspiring. but it seems to be too complex and  `we can tighten up that convex hull` section has the notebook killed. did you run the notebook yourself?