# filter simplices out of scipy.spatial.Delaunay

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay

**Short version:**

Is it possible to create a new scipy.spatial.Delaunay object with a subset of the triangles (2D data) from an existing object?

The goal would be to use the find_simplex method on the new object with filtered out simplices.

**Similar but not quite the same**

[matplotlib contour/contourf of **concave** non-gridded data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426095/matplotlib-contour-contourf-of-concave-non-gridded-data)

[How to deal with the (undesired) triangles that form between the edges of my geometry when using Triangulation in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457964/how-to-deal-with-the-undesired-triangles-that-form-between-the-edges-of-my-geo)

**Long version:**

I am looking at lat-lon data that I regrid with scipy.interpolate.griddata like in the pseudo-code below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
from scipy.interpolate.interpnd import _ndim_coords_from_arrays

#lat shape (a,b): 2D array of latitude values
#lon shape (a,b): 2D array of longitude values
#x shape (a,b): 2D array of variable of interest at lat and lon

# lat-lon data
nonan = ~np.isnan(lat)
flat_lat = lat[nonan]
flat_lon = lon[nonan]
flat_x = x[nonan]

# regular lat-lon grid for regridding
lon_ar = np.arange(loni,lonf,resolution)
lat_ar = np.arange(lati,latf,resolution)
lon_grid, lat_grid = np.meshgrid(lon_ar,lat_ar)

# regrid
x_grid = griddata((flat_lon,flat_lat),flat_x,(lon_grid,lat_grid), method='nearest')

# filter out extrapolated values
cloud_points = _ndim_coords_from_arrays((flat_lon,flat_lat))
regrid_points = _ndim_coords_from_arrays((lon_grid.ravel(),lat_grid.ravel()))
tri = Delaunay(cloud_points)
outside_hull = tri.find_simplex(regrid_points) < 0
x_grid[outside_hull.reshape(x_grid.shape)] = np.nan

# filter out large triangles ??
# it would be easy if I could "subset" tri into a new scipy.spatial.Delaunay object
# new_tri = ??
# outside_hull = new_tri.find_simplex(regrid_points) < 0
```

The problem is that the convex hull has low quality (very large, shown in blue in example below) triangles that I would like to filter out as they don't represent the data well. I know how to filter them out in input points, but not in the regridded output. Here is the filter function:

```
def filter_large_triangles(
    points: np.ndarray, tri: Optional[Delaunay] = None, coeff: float = 2.0
):
    """
    Filter out triangles that have an edge > coeff * median(edge)
    Inputs:
        tri: scipy.spatial.Delaunay object
        coeff: triangles with an edge > coeff * median(edge) will be filtered out
    Outputs:
        valid_slice: boolean array that selects "normal" triangles
    """
    if tri is None:
        tri = Delaunay(points)

    edge_lengths = np.zeros(tri.vertices.shape)
    seen = {}
    # loop over triangles
    for i, vertex in enumerate(tri.vertices):
        # loop over edges
        for j in range(3):
            id0 = vertex[j]
            id1 = vertex[(j + 1) % 3]

            # avoid calculating twice for non-border edges
            if (id0,id1) in seen:
                edge_lengths[i, j] = seen[(id0,id1)]
            else:    
                edge_lengths[i, j] = np.linalg.norm(points[id1] - points[id0])

                seen[(id0,id1)] = edge_lengths[i, j]

    median_edge = np.median(edge_lengths.flatten())

    valid_slice = np.all(edge_lengths < coeff * median_edge, axis=1)

    return valid_slice
```

The bad triangles are shown in blue below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
no_large_triangles = filter_large_triangles(cloud_points,tri)
fig,ax = plt.subplot()
ax.triplot(points[:,0],points[:,1],tri.simplices,c='blue')
ax.triplot(points[:,0],points[:,1],tri.simplices[no_large_triangles],c='green')
plt.show()
```

[image: Large simplices on the sides of the domain][image: zoom on large simplices]

Is it possible to create a new scipy.spatial.Delaunay object with only the `no_large_triangles` simplices? The goal would be to use the find_simplex method on that new object to easily filter out points.

As an alternative how could I find the indices of points in `regrid_points` that fall inside the blue triangles? (`tri.simplices[~no_large_triangles]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is possible to modify the Delaunay object for the purpose of using find_simplex on a subset of simplices, but it seems only with the bruteforce algorithm.

```
# filter out extrapolated values
cloud_points = _ndim_coords_from_arrays((flat_lon,flat_lat))
regrid_points = _ndim_coords_from_arrays((lon_grid.ravel(),lat_grid.ravel()))
tri = Delaunay(cloud_points)
outside_hull = tri.find_simplex(regrid_points) < 0

# filter out large triangles
large_triangles = ~filter_large_triangles(cloud_points,tri)
large_triangle_ids = np.where(large_triangles)[0]
subset_tri = tri # this doesn't preserve tri, effectively just a renaming
# the _find_simplex_bruteforce method only needs the simplices and neighbors
subset_tri.nsimplex = large_triangle_ids.size
subset_tri.simplices = tri.simplices[large_triangles]
subset_tri.neighbors = tri.neighbors[large_triangles]

# update neighbors
for i,triangle in enumerate(subset_tri.neighbors):
    for j,neighbor_id in enumerate(triangle):
        if neighbor_id in large_triangle_ids:
            # reindex the neighbors to match the size of the subset
            subset_tri.neighbors[i,j] = np.where(large_triangle_ids==neighbor_id)[0]
        elif neighbor_id>=0 and (neighbor_id not in large_triangle_ids):
            # that neighbor was a "normal" triangle that should not exist in the subset
            subset_tri.neighbors[i,j] = -1
inside_large_triangles = subset_tri.find_simplex(regrid_points,bruteforce=True) >= 0

invalid_slice = np.logical_or(outside_hull,inside_large_triangles)
x_grid[invalid_slice.reshape(x_grid.shape)] = np.nan
```

Showing that the new Delaunay object has only the subset of large triangles

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplot()
ax.triplot(cloud_points[:,0],cloud_points[:,1],subset_tri.simplices,color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Plotting x_grid with pcolormesh before the filtering for large triangles (zoomed in the blue circle above):

[image]

After the filtering:

[image]